# Rspec cannot connect server error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I’m working with `rspec` to test rails app
My code to test controller is like below

```
require "spec_helper"
require "support/factory_girl"

RSpec.describe UsersController, :type => :controller do
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

  let(:other_user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

  before { login user }

  describe "POST #follow" do
    it "adds that user to friends" do
      binding.pry
      post :follow, id: other_user, format: :js
      expect(response).to have_http_status(:ok)
      expect(user.following? other_user).to be_truthy
    end
  end
```

However, this causes connection fail error 
Which is

```
UsersController POST #follow adds that user to friends
     Failure/Error: let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
     Faraday::ConnectionFailed:
```

Is there something else I’ve missed while setting environment?
I'm not sure why this kind of access error occurs, since I've granted full privilege for the local db access
Attached below is full error message

```
Faraday::ConnectionFailed:
       Couldn't connect to server
     # /Users/joohyung/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/typhoeus-1.1.2/lib/typhoeus/adapters/faraday.rb:106:in `block in request'
     # /Users/joohyung/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/typhoeus-1.1.2/lib/typhoeus/request/callbacks.rb:128:in `block in execute_callbacks'
     # /Users/joohyung/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/typhoeus-1.1.2/lib/typhoeus/request/callbacks.rb:127:in `each'
     # /Users/joohyung/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/typhoeus-1.1.2/lib/typhoeus/request/callbacks.rb:127:in `execute_callbacks'
     # /Users/joohyung/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/typhoeus-1.1.2/lib/typhoeus/request/operations.rb:35:in `finish'
     # /Users/joohyung/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/typhoeus-1.1.2/lib/typhoeus/easy_factory.rb:159:in `block in set_callback'
     # /Users/joohyung/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/ethon-0.10.1/lib/ethon/easy/response_callbacks.rb:68:in `block in complete'
     # /Users/joohyung/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/ethon-0.10.1/lib/ethon/easy/response_callbacks.rb:68:in `each'
     # /Users/joohyung/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/ethon-0.10.1/lib/ethon/easy/response_callbacks.rb:68:in `complete'
     # /Users/joohyung/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/ethon-0.10.1/lib/ethon/easy/operations.rb:33:in `perform'
     # /Users/joohyung/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/typhoeus-1.1.2/lib/typhoeus/request/operations.rb:16:in `run'
     # /Users/joohyung/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/typhoeus-1.1.2/lib/typhoeus/request/cacheable.rb:18:in `run'
     # /Users/joohyung/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/typhoeus-1.1.2/lib/typhoeus/request/block_connection.rb:31:in `run'
     # /Users/joohyung/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/typhoeus-1.1.2/lib/typhoeus/request/stubbable.rb:25:in `run'
     # /Users/joohyung/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/typhoeus-1.1.2/lib/typhoeus/request/before.rb:26:in `run'
     # /Users/joohyung/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/typhoeus-1.1.2/lib/typhoeus/adapters/faraday.rb:82:in `perform_request'
     # /Users/joohyung/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/typhoeus-1.1.2/lib/typhoeus/adapters/faraday.rb:72:in `call'
     # /Users/joohyung/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/searchkick-2.3.1/lib/searchkick/middleware.rb:9:in `call'
     # /Users/joohyung/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/faraday-0.9.2/lib/faraday/rack_builder.rb:139:in `build_response'
     # /Users/joohyung/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/faraday-0.9.2/lib/faraday/connection.rb:377:in `run_request'
     # /Users/joohyung/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/elasticsearch-transport-5.0.4/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/http/faraday.rb:23:in `block in perform_request'
     # /Users/joohyung/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/elasticsearch-transport-5.0.4/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/base.rb:262:in `perform_request'
     # /Users/joohyung/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/elasticsearch-transport-5.0.4/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/http/faraday.rb:20:in `perform_request'
     # /Users/joohyung/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/elasticsearch-transport-5.0.4/lib/elasticsearch/transport/client.rb:131:in `perform_request'
     # /Users/joohyung/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/elasticsearch-api-5.0.4/lib/elasticsearch/api/actions/bulk.rb:95:in `bulk'
     # /Users/joohyung/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/searchkick-2.3.1/lib/searchkick/indexer.rb:18:in `perform'
     # /Users/joohyung/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/searchkick-2.3.1/lib/searchkick/logging.rb:126:in `perform'
     # /Users/joohyung/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/searchkick-2.3.1/lib/searchkick/indexer.rb:11:in `queue'
     # /Users/joohyung/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/searchkick-2.3.1/lib/searchkick/index.rb:496:in `bulk_index_helper'
     # /Users/joohyung/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/searchkick-2.3.1/lib/searchkick/index.rb:72:in `store'
     # /Users/joohyung/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/searchkick-2.3.1/lib/searchkick/logging.rb:28:in `block in store'
     # /Users/joohyung/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.8/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
     # /Users/joohyung/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.8/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
     # /Users/joohyung/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.8/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
     # /Users/joohyung/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/searchkick-2.3.1/lib/searchkick/logging.rb:27:in `store'
     # /Users/joohyung/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/searchkick-2.3.1/lib/searchkick/index.rb:122:in `reindex_record'
     # /Users/joohyung/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/searchkick-2.3.1/lib/searchkick/model.rb:125:in `reindex'
     # /Users/joohyung/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:432:in `block in make_lambda'
     # /Users/joohyung/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:228:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
     # /Users/joohyung/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:506:in `block in call'
     # /Users/joohyung/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:506:in `each'
     # /Users/joohyung/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:506:in `call'
     # /Users/joohyung/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `__run_callbacks__'
     # /Users/joohyung/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_save_callbacks'
     # /Users/joohyung/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:302:in `create_or_update'
     # /Users/joohyung/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:142:in `save!'
     # /Users/joohyung/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/validations.rb:43:in `save!'
     # /Users/joohyung/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:29:in `save!'
     # /Users/joohyung/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:291:in `block in save!'
     # /Users/joohyung/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:351:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
     # /Users/joohyung/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/test_after_commit-1.1.0/lib/test_after_commit/database_statements.rb:11:in `block in transaction'
     # /Users/joohyung/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `block in transaction'
     # /Users/joohyung/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:184:in `within_new_transaction'
     # /Users/joohyung/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `transaction'
     # /Users/joohyung/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/test_after_commit-1.1.0/lib/test_after_commit/database_statements.rb:5:in `transaction'
     # /Users/joohyung/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:220:in `transaction'
     # /Users/joohyung/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:348:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
     # /Users/joohyung/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:291:in `save!'
     # /Users/joohyung/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/configuration.rb:18:in `block in initialize'
     # /Users/joohyung/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/evaluation.rb:15:in `create'
     # /Users/joohyung/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/strategy/create.rb:12:in `block in result'
     # /Users/joohyung/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/strategy/create.rb:9:in `tap'
     # /Users/joohyung/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/strategy/create.rb:9:in `result'
     # /Users/joohyung/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/factory.rb:42:in `run'
     # /Users/joohyung/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/factory_runner.rb:29:in `block in run'
     # /Users/joohyung/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.8/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
     # /Users/joohyung/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/factory_runner.rb:28:in `run'
     # /Users/joohyung/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/strategy_syntax_method_registrar.rb:20:in `block in define_singular_strategy_method'
     # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: is there a connection failure reason given? Something right after  Faraday::ConnectionFailed:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the exception backtrace it looks like the error is thrown when trying to connect to Elasticsearch.

Make sure your elasticsearch server is running before you run your test suite.

Comment: Check if elasticsearch is running from the command line with `curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/?pretty'`. If you suspect your indexes are not in a clean state before you run your tests/specs, run `curl -XDELETE 'localhost:9200/test*'`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your test is attempting to connect to an Elasticsearch server but cant. You should either disable Elasticsearch for your test environment or set up a configuration that works for your test environment.